# Git branches and creation of new files

Tags: git

I have a repository where I created a new branch "test" and added a few files, made a few modifications. However, I see that when I switch back to the "master" branch the files I created in "test" are present in "master".

Why does this happen?

[EDIT]
I figured out the reason for my confusion. I had performed a "git pull" which caused a merge. As a result I had files from my "test" branch in my "master. I hadn't realized that pull would be a fetch followed by a commit.

Comment: That's how it works. You need to either commit or stash your changes before switching

Comment: There is clearly no research at all in this question; any git tutorial, man page, book, or google query will tell you that a CVS will not track your files until you tell it to do it. I don't see how this question got two upvotes.

Comment: I've updated the question with an edit which demonstrates the reason for my confusion, I apologize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't commit your files in the branch they remain on your workspace.
So while in your branch you should:

```
git add your_new_files
git commit
```

When your switch on the master the files aren't there anymore.

When you're in the test branch, you'll see your new files as *untracked* until you dont add them to the index (with git add) and them commit them (git commit).
To see if you have untracked files:

```
 git status
```